# Is time comes to not worry about memory

Tags: .net, memory-management, 64-bit

About a year ago we are developed for internal use inprocess MOLAP engine that perform aggregation of a large amount of data.
We using it only as a part of our platform because we was sure that such a system without custom memory alocation, paging etc is not viable solution, but some time ago Microsoft published beta version of [PowerPivot](http://www.powerpivot.com/) - tool that perform multidimensional analysis of flat object collections and visualization via Excel pivot tables\charts with the same 'issues' on x86 as our app.

**And the question is**

Should we ignore memory and simply deploy x64 version without any memory pain. and x86 versions with comments in user docs?

Comment: I think there was... but I forgot =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean, "is it acceptable to release a desktop app that can only work properly on x64 workstations"?

I guess it depends on who your customers are. Personally, I think 32 bit platforms are going to be around for quite a while, esp. in corporate environments that are interested in desktop OLAP.

If you mean: is it acceptable for a server application to be 64bit exclusive, I guess my answer would be "yes" a lot faster.

Comment: yeah you are right about what I mean. but about _work properly_ - powerpivot also does not work properly on x86 in your terms, but microsoft deploy it without worry about that.

Comment: Note, on PCs that have to run 32-bit OSs for corporate reasons, they can still run a 64-bit guest OS in VirtualBox or similar. (Disclosure: I work for the company that produces VirtualBox.)

Comment: @Sergey Mirvoda: well, I guess it depends on what "properly" means. If the software is functional, just not perfect...that could be completely ok. If it crashes, and people lose their analysis result...then maybe not so much.

What you could do though is start marketing your product and recommend it for the time being to be accessed via Citrix or similar, or via a virt. solution like suggested by Tom Hawtin. If you sell, invest and improve

@Tom Hawtin: hat tip to you and yours for creating a great product! I love virtualbox, i think it's the best desktop virtualization software on the market.

Comment: @Tom what is memory limits for 64-bit guest OS under 32-bit host? Can VirtualBox use AWE?

Comment: @Sergey: Good question. I have no idea...